# Information flow question

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Which SE site can I ask the below question to?

> How does [information flow](https://www.scielo.br/j/pci/a/fpdT9MrS9yCx3GLHsRfyn8q/?lang=pt#:%7E:text=O%20fluxo%20de%20informa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20%C3%A9,informacionais%20e%20possibilitando%20a%20gera%C3%A7%C3%A3o)  on the Internet?
>
> > The information flow is a dynamic communication process, which takes place in different information environments, with the objective of transmitting information, with added value, from a sender to a receiver or multiple receivers, aiming to respond to the most complex informational needs and enabling the generation of knowledge.
>
> > The concept of Information Flow is used by three different fields of knowledge: Semiotics, which considers the influence of flows in the construction of discourse; Information Theory, strongly influenced by mathematical and computer models; and Communication Theory, which identifies such flows with the geopolitical and geocultural organization of the world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a clear question and is not suitable anywhere on the Stack Exchange Network.

Information flows at different levels, in different manners, and for different purposes. Any of the following areas could have questions asked around them:

- How political information is disseminated between parties and voters in a particular political context.
- How libraries, universities, and other educational institutions share and make available scientific data.
- How certain chat protocols work on a technical level.
- How certain Internet protocols work at the word or packet level.
- Troubleshooting techniques for certain data communication issues, such as dropped packets or frequently dropped connections.
- The similarities and differences between how different population groups use chat and communication apps in different ways.
- How certain governments regulate the flow of data, for instance through official firewalls, monitoring systems, or criminal penalties for sharing certain data.

Even the questions above are mostly too unclear or broad for the network. The Stack Exchange network is only suitable for *specific* questions that can receive concise answers. Questions that have no real answer or that could only be answered by a book-length answer are not allowed.

For your original question, someone could write an entire book, doctoral dissertation, or similar just exploring a single aspect of Internet communication. There's no way that anyone can meaningfully answer it in a few paragraphs.